# script not found or unable to stat in /cgi-bin/favicon.ico

Tags: apache, perl, cgi, favicon

In my Apache 2.4 error log file I constantly get the following error: (takes up a huge amount of space in the Apache error log file)

```
AH02811: script not found or unable to stat: /somedomain.com/public_html/cgi-bin/favicon.ico
```

**/somedomain.com/public_html/cgi-bin/** is configured as the ScriptAlias directory where Perl scripts are served from and .ico or image files cannot be served from this directory.

What is probably happening here is that https://www.somedomain.com/cgi-bin/something.cgi is served up but the user's web browser is looking for https://www.somedomain.com/cgi-bin/favicon.ico ?

How do I serve favicon.ico to the user's browser (to avoid triggering the error) or how do I at least get rid of this particular error in the Apache error log file?

Comment: hmmm, Browsers only look for `favicon.ico` in the "root directory"
 or where specified by `<link rel="icon">` or `<link rel="shortcut">` element in the response.

Comment: I'd first look to see what sorts of IP addresses and user-agents are making this weird request. And, as for caring about it in the server logs, I'd just get over it. All sorts of things make weird requests to my servers. If they get really annoying, I just block by IP, user-agent string, or whatever shows the pattern.